# How to terminate a recursive function after a specific time?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, recursion

I have a recursive function in C++ and I need to immediately terminate the function including all calls which have recursively made after a specific time, say 60 secs.
I have tried the following but doesn't work. takesTooLong is a global variable but if its value changes to 1 in one call, other calls keep seeing it as 0.
The OS is **Ubuntu 12.10**.

main() is something like this:

```
int main()
{
    takesTooLong = 0;
    startTime = clock();
    RecursiveFunction();
    endTime = clock();
    printf("Elapsed time: %f", CalculateElapsedTime(startTime, endTime));
    return 0;
}
```

My recursive function:

```
void RecursiveFunction(Some Parameters)
{
    if (takesTooLong == 1)
        return;

    endTime = clock();
    differenceTime = CalculateElapsedTime(startTime, endTime);
    if (differenceTime > MAX_SECONDS)
    {
        takesTooLong = 1;
    }

    if (takesTooLong == 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n && takesTooLong == 0; i++)
        {
            RecursiveFunction(Some Updated Parameters);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you have a question about your code, it would be helpful if you posted the code here so we can see it. "Any ideas?" is far too vague.

Comment: Make the initial time a parameter and the time check a part of the recursion logic. It won't terminate all the calls immediately since the stack of recusive calls needs to be "unrolled" but it's close enough.

Comment: maybe a thread or separate process which you can observe and kill ;)

Comment: @sled I think this kind of programs use just one thread. So if I kill that thread, actually the whole program will be terminated.

Comment: @sled: that's kinda like using grenade launcher to kill a fly. There's no need for threads in something this simple.

Comment: What operating system?  System timers are good at this kind of thing.

Comment: @Duck Sorry. Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Global, or passed-down, 'abort' boolean.  Set it from a pool timer or from another sleep() thread.  Continually checking the time at each level is a waste of CPU.  Many recursive algorithms are simple, and making a system call for time, all the time, is expensive.

Comment: Get one timestamp before first function call, take timestamps on recursive funtion calls and put a statement that returs when the difference of timestamps reaches the desired time (pass first timestamp as argument or have it as a class member object to use it in fucntion check).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
typedef ??? Time;//time type
Time getCurrentTime(); //returns time. Or ticks. Anything you could use to measure time.

void recursiveFunction(Time startTime){       
    ...//do something here
    Time currentTime = getCurrentTime();                
    if ((currentTime - startTime) > limit)
        return;
    recursiveFunction(startTime);
}

void recursiveFunction(){
     Time startTime = getCurrentTime();
     recursiveFunction(startTime);
}
```

Comment: This kind of terminating may not be the quickest way. Suppose your recursiveFunction goes very deep. When the function _returns_ in a level, we have to wait that all the ancestor calls _return_ too. Now suppose that in each level of recursion, n calls get pushed to the stack. That can make a huge amount of ancestors.

Comment: Why did you use the second recursiveFunction?

Comment: @Mowji: *"may not be the quickest way"* It is the only way. The alternatives are `exit`, `abort`, longjmp, terminating thread, and throwing an exception. Termination/jumping ignores destructors, and should be avoided. Simulating flow control with exception is a bad taste. *"we have to wait that all the"* And? Throw an exception, you'll get the same thing - returning from deepest level one by one.  *"n calls get pushed to the stack"* I don't see the problem. If your recursive call does not fit into stack, remove recursion. `std::deque`(and similar) works for that.

Comment: @Mowji: *"n calls get pushed to the stack"* Besides, that's the nature of recursion. During every call *something* (return address, possibly stack unwind info) is always pushed onto stack. If you don't like it - don't use recursion. *"Why did you use the second recursiveFunction"* Because otherwise you would get unnecessary if/else at every level of recursive call. It is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still have to unroll the stack but the alternatives are all ugly, the best probably being longjmp.  If you need greater resolution than seconds, or you want to measure process/kernel time rather than wall clock time, use alternatives like `timer_create` or `setitimer`.

```
void alarmHandler (int sig)
{
    timedOut = 1;
}


    signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);

    alarm(60);
    RecursiveFunction();
    alarm(0);

    if (timedOut)
    {
        //report something
        timedOut = 0;
    }


void RecursiveFunction(Some Parameters)
{
    if (timedOut)
        return;

    //........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to exit an unknown number of recursions is by throwing an exception. Since you're doing it at most once every 60 seconds, this isn't too bad. Just make it a `class TimeLimitExceeded : public std::runtime_error` and catch that in the top level wrapper†.

† Most recursive functions should not be called directly, but via a non-recursive wrapper. The signature of the recursive function usually is inconvenient for callers, as it contains implementation details that are irrelevant to the caller.